# Как добавлять userа при регистрации, чтобы этому человеку присваивался индекс и закреплялся за ним

Tags: python, python-3.x

Такой вопрос, хочу сделать регистрационное поле для Usera, но есть проблемы, нет знаний о том, как сделать небольшую базу данных, чтобы хранить там индекс человека, можете помочь ? По сути я хочу, чтобы при регистрации за пользователем хранился определённый индекс, который потом никогда не менялся, индекс выбирает функция Random.randit,если такой индекс уже есть то программа заново генерирует новый, пока не будет уникальным, при чём после индекса у пользователя просят пароль и т.д пример кода внизу

```
import random
    import time
    index=random.randint(0,1000)
    family=""
    vozrast=0;
    def registration ():
        print("Введите ваше имя",end='',)
        name=input(":")
        print("Введите вашу фамилию",end='',)
        family=input(":")
        print("Введите ваш возраст",end='',)
        vozrast=int(input(":"))
        if vozrast>15 and vozrast<100:    
            print("Ваш индекс: ",index,"Только по нему вы сможете зайти в свой аккаунт" )
            print("Хотите войти ?")
            ans_4=input(": ")
            if ans_4=="Да" or ans_4=="да":
                print("Введите ваш индекс")
                index_1= int(input(": "))
                if index==index_1:
                    print("Здравствуйте !",name , family,"\nПридумайте пароль для входа в аккаунт",end='')
                    parole=input(": ")
                    while len(parole)<5:
                        print("Длинна пароля должна быть больше 5 символов!")
                        parole=input("Введите пароль : ")
                    parole_1=input("Повторите пароль: ")
                    while parole!=parole_1:
                        print("Пароли не совпадают!")
                        parole_1=input("Повторите пароль: ")
                    if parole==parole_1:
                        print("Пароли совпали!")
                    print("Доступ к аккаунту доступен!")
                    input("Нажмите Enter для закрытия программы!!!")
                elif index!=index_1:
                    print("Вы неправильно ввели индекс")
        elif vozrast<15:
            print("Вы слишком молоды для данного контакта ! Приходите через" ,15 -vozrast,"лет)")
            input("Нажмите Enter для закрытия программы!!!")
        elif vozrast>100:
            print("Такого не может быть!")
    
                
    print("Хотите зарегестрировать ?")
    ans_1=input(": ")
    if ans_1=="Да" or ans_1=="да":
        registration()
    else:
        print("Хотите войти?")
        ans_2=input(": ")
        if ans_2=="Да" or ans_2=="да":
            print("Введите ваш индекс")
            index_1= int(input(": "))
            if index==index_1:
                print("Здравствуйте !", family)
                
            else:
                print("Неверно!!!")
                print("Хотите пройти регистрацию?")
                ans_3=input(": ")
                if ans_3=="Да" or ans_3=="да":
                    registration();
                else:
                    print("До свидания!")
        else:
            print("Всего хорошего!")
```

Comment: В чем ваш вопрос заключается?

Comment: как можно реализовать присвоение индекса пользователю и как сделать так, чтобы он сохранялся в какую-нибудь базу и например, если выбрать определённый индекс, то высветится вся его информация и уже от правильности пароля впускать или нет USERA

Comment: @cwanniname, делайте через базу данных: создаете таблицу User, там будет поле id primary key, оно может автоинкрементироваться, если его не указывать

Answer (score 2):

**Если вы ещё не знакомы с базами данных - начните с чего-то простого**

Конечно, можете придумать способ хранить данные в обычном *.txt файле, но всё-таки советую вам начать изучать Sqlite3 - идеально подойдёт для быстрого старта в мире хранения информации.

[Замечательная статья на Хабрахабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/321510/) вам поможет. Удачи!